# Jqplot DateAxis rendering is not proper

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I tried to plot data useage per day using `jqPlot` along with its `DateAxisRenderer`, the data was static to test the graph, but I found that the points on graph are not corresponding to the exact date on the grid.

Is there a better tool out there to do this more accurately? I need to render light and interactive graphs on browser using `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can fix this problem.

You can use tickInterval:'1 day' after you set min:'yyyy-mm-dd'  and max:'yyyy-mm-dd' of xais.
This is my example (use tickInterval:'7 day'):

```
   xaxis:{
        min:'2010-12-14',
        max:'2011-01-06',
        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        rendererOptions:{tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer},
        tickInterval:'7 day',            
        tickOptions:{
          fontFamily:'Verdata',
          fontSize:'10pt',
          formatString:'%b %#d, %Y',
          angle:-30
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the data axis renderer for months -- no bugs or problems.  I did run into problems because times in JS are measured in milliseconds.