# jqplot force ticks to be every 15 minutes

Tags: jquery, time, jqplot

I have data that is showing info for the last 24 hours per 15 minutes.
I'd like to be able to plot this data with the xaxis showing increments of 15 minutes or each hour. There will be too much data to show in the same view so i know it will cramp up and look like one block. I want to be able to use the zoom to then zoom in on these so we can see the per 15 minues of the time we have zoomed in on. The problem I am having even though the data is per 15 minutes the x axis shoing tick with odd times like 06:37. I want it to allways be either an hour or per 15 minues is this possible?

I have tried using tickInterval: '15 minutes' but it doesnt seem to make a difference.
Each time i run this i may have more or less values for each so even setting the number of ticks is not helpful unless i cna change this on zoom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem appears to relate to what I confronted myself a while ago. The only way to get the tickInterval to working with date axis is to set min and max parameters. [Please find an example in my other answer to a similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10233111/613495)