# jqPlot displays y-ticks twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

using two DateAxisSeries (x-axis) with normal integer values on the y-axis my jqPlot renders the y-ticks twice.

Like this:

```
2|
2|
1|
1|
0|______________________________________
```

This causes the values being rendered not properly, except the face that this obviously shouldn't happen.

Serie 1: [["07.03.2012", 2], ["17.03.2012", 2], ["28.03.2012", 1]]

Serie 2: [["01.03.2012", 1], ["08.03.2012", 1], ["14.03.2012", 1], ["24.03.2012", 1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never had a chart with two Date axes, but I suspect the problem you are facing is the same as for one.

Did you remembered to **set the min and max parameters** for each axis? I have mentioned this solution already in one of my answers. [Please find it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10233111/613495)

This appears to be the only way of getting the data axis to work properly since otherwise it is being auto sized chance the duplication of values.

Comment: @daemonfire300 can you make a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) with a sample so I can work with it from there?

Answer (score 2):

What you using for your y-axis formatString? I ran into this same problem because I was inadvertently using formatString='%d', causing the y-value 1.5 to render as 1.

You should be able to fix this by removing/modifying your yaxis formatString or specifying a specific tickInterval, e.g.

```
yaxis: {
    min:          0,
    max: {{ max_count }} + 1,
    tickInterval: 1,
    tickOptions:  {
        formatString:'%d'
    }
}
```