# How to convert string into an array for jqplot

Tags: php, jqplot

I am trying to create a line chart using Jqplot.

I am producing a string in PHP like this -

```
$retstring = "[['Q2 2011', 3.7813],['Q1 2011', 3.7813],['Q3 2011', 3.9000]],  [['Q2 2011', 3.6563],['Q1 2011', 3.6563],['Q3 2011', 3.5765]]";
```

As you can see from the string structure, I want to plot two lines.

The `$retstring` is being passed to JavaScript function using simple AJAX.  When I get this string in JavaScript function, how do I convert that into array to be passed to JqPlot ?

Comment: It looks like this is just a json_encoded array structure. Using `json_decode($retstring)` you would get an array like `array(array('Q2 2011', 3.7813), array(..), ...)` which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related to [the question I have already answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10191122/613495)

Therefore, [please check my answer there.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10233111/613495)

Particularly the code sample, which you will fined towards the bottom of my answer, where you could see how the date you provide could be used.

**EDIT:** When it goes to the main part of the problem, the decoding bit, do just as @mahok says use the `json_decode`. I wonder if you actually will not experience problems since, technically the `String` you have is not a proper [JSON](http://json.org/). In JSON `String`s are wrapped in double quotes (`""`) not in single once (`''`). Therefore, you might need to replace them appropriately but other than that the method would do the trick.

I was suspecting that the `json_decode` could have problem with this encoding and [as they say it here, the method will return `null` in this case, please see example 3.](https://www.php.net/json_decode)